# "awk-ing/sed-ing" a string in RUBY

Tags: ruby, string, bash, awk, sed

Here is my Ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'

third_way=Socket.ip_address_list.select{|intf| intf.ipv4?}
#the above variable is an **array**
puts "%s" % ["With Percent S Percent #{third_way}"]
puts ["Nothing fancey. Straight puts... #{third_way}"]

third_way.each do |ip|
  puts "%s" % ["gsub1 #{ip}"].gsub(/[<>\[\]]/, "")
  puts "%s" % ["gsub2 #{ip}"].gsub("<>[]", "")
end
```

Output:

```
With Percent S Percent [#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.252.54>]
Nothing fancey. Straight puts... [#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.252.54>]
./myip.rb:36:in `block in <main>': undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x000000010cdbf8 (NoMethodError)
        from ./myip.rb:35:in `each'
        from ./myip.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Here is my bash code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=("[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]")
IFS_OLD="$IFS"
IFS=","
for ip in $array; do
  echo "$ip" | awk '{print $2}' | sed "s/>.*//g"
done
IFS="$IFS_OLD"
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.4
```

Now for my question. How do I do what I did in bash, in ruby?

I can't seem to get this to work in ruby, whereas in bash it's dead easy!!

Comment: It would be useful to see how you're obtaining the data and its exact format in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my resulting code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'
puts Socket.ip_address_list.select{|intf| intf.ipv4?}.to_s.scan(/(?<=: )[\d.]+(?=>)/)

#or we can break it up a bit more.

ip_arr = Socket.ip_address_list.select{|intf| intf.ipv4?}
puts ip_arr.to_s.scan(/(?<=: )[\d.]+(?=>)/)
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.4
```

The `to_s` was required to convert the array to a string.
After the conversion, I went with Tom Fenech's way because it avoids looping.
And that awk statement is very clever.

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in ruby but this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

str = "[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]"
puts str.scan(/(?<=: )[\d.]+(?=>)/)
```

The regular expression could be simpler but I've used positive lookahead and lookbehind assertion to ensure that the IP address are followed and preceded by the correct characters.

By the way, here's how you could go about it in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]"
awk -F': |>' -v RS=, '{print $2}' <<<"$string"
```

This uses a custom Input Field Separator and Record Separator to split the string into the required fields.

Output (either way):

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby can do the same from bash too :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$ echo "[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]" | ruby -ne 
'$_.gsub(/\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b/).each{|x| puts x}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple in ruby:

```
var = "[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]"
puts var.scan(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/).join("\n")
```

And in bash using grep:

```
grep -Po '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' <<< '[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]'
```

Both outputs:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

var = "[#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>, #<Addrinfo: 192.168.0.4>]"

var.split.each do |y|
    puts y.gsub(/>|,|\]/, '') unless y =~ /Addr/
end

### Or, you can write above loop in shorthand notation as:
### var.split.each {|y| puts y.gsub(/>|,|\]/, '') unless y =~ /Addr/}
```

**Output:**

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.4
```